# How to install oci8 in php 7.4.9 in windows 10

Tags: php, windows-10, oracle9i, oci8, php-7.4

I am using windows 10(x64). an using php 7.4 and download from here...
https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.4

I unzip it and placed in c:\php7.4.9 and uncomment some extension in php.ini
I need to connect to oracle9i and mysql, so I uncomment the oci8_12c, oci8 and pdo_mysql
my pdo_mysql works fine.

Everytime I run php. it will prompt my oci and oci8_12c are not valid win32 command
and the phpinfo() shows seems my oci is not installed....

I tried to find some other dll from pecl to replace the original one.
Still the same.

anyone can help
Thanks a lot.

Comment: For PHP OCI8 you also need to install some Oracle Client libraries (see the [installation instructions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php)) and also appropriate VS Redistributable if you installed [Oracle Instant Client](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html).  Make sure the Oracle client is the same 32 or 64-bit as PHP (not the OS).  One problem you will have is finding a version of Oracle Client that works on Win 10 and also connects to a 9i DB.  I don't think 11.2 client was certified on Win 10.